# How to copy header and footer from one pdf to another

Tags: java, pdfbox, itextpdf

I need to create a report in pdf in java. This report is being created in two steps. 
1. Create textual part of report on first page (with Header/Footer)
2. Create graphic part of report in next page. (using itext pdf)
For the graphics part, I need to copy header/footer from first page and add this to all other pages. Can somebody guide me how I can achieve this in itext or any other similar library.

Comment: Could you copy/paste a part of your current code ?

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. You should create a PDF with a header and a footer (nothing else; call it "company stationery" with the company's "letterhead"). Then create a Form XObject (a `PdfTemplate` in iText language) and add this company stationery in the background of each page. This will keep the filesize reduced and your PDF will be more "elegant" under the hood.